# How to identify the first user time login

Tags: javascript, html, database

How to identify the first time user login and that time display some alert message  in javascript 
can any body help me please ? 
guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a column in the user table `LAST_LOGIN DateTime`. Every time the user logs in update that record.

By default make the column NULL. If `LAST_LOGIN === null` then it's the first time the user has logged in.

Comment: This does not actually seem like a valid option unless you provide more logic dictating that this can only be done/dictated prior to the server rendering the page...Okay you have a `LAST_LOGIN` that is set to null when a user is added, as soon as **any user** logs in that value is updated. There is no chance a user can access a login-restricted page without having that `LAST_LOGIN` value set as they obviously have to login to see it.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use cookies:

```
if (document.cookie != 'visited'){
  alert('Hey there, new user!');
  document.cookie = 'visited';
}
```

However, if the user clears history or cookies in between, this will be reset.

A better way would be to have your server track which users have visited before.

Answer (score 1):

Make a first_login column in your DB.
Check if it is empty when a user tries to login, if it is, populate the field with the current date & time, else do nothing.

```
   <?php
       // Assuming you know the user is logged in & validated.
       if($flogin === ""){
          // Query: "UPDATE SET first_login = NOW() WHERE user_id = '$logged_in_user_id'"
       }else {
         // Get first_login and display to the user
       }
   ?>
```

Not really sure if you know what you're doing since you're asking how to display something to the user, so, for more info please clarify more.

Comment: Yeah Dude i Just do i like only firstlogin default when user login in then popup displayed and after agree firstlogin set to true then next time onwards wont show its works